# In Apex Legends, Players are very jerky/laggy, stuttering players

Tags: networking, performance, apex-legends

**TLDR; network sucks, framerate great**

The game RENDERS at about 40fps, which is fine, but the players move at about 3 FPS.

I'm certain it's not a framerate issue as I can still look around and it runs at a buttery 45 FPS at all times regardless, but all the other players jolt, it's like they freeze, then skip forward, then freeze, then skip forward. It makes it really hard to enjoy combat. It happens with enemies, and teammates. it's almost as if there's really high packet loss or something. It happens constantly about every half a second.

Voice chat is also distorted and choppy in the game, but not in discord. And as far as I can tell, no other games are affected. They are all buttery smooth networking, but not Apex Legends. It's a nightmare to play. The enemy stops & starts so much I can't fight.

I'm on a wired network connection.

My Data Centers ping looks good (I'm in Los Angeles)
[image]

My Internet connection is solid
[image]

nVidia Dump:

```
NVIDIA System Information report created on: 03/19/2019 17:47:34
System name: JONNYSDESKTOP

[Display]
Operating System:   Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit
DirectX version:    12.0 
GPU processor:      GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Driver version:     416.94
Driver Type:        Standard
Direct3D API version:   12
Direct3D feature level: 12_1
CUDA Cores:     768 
Core clock:     1354 MHz 
Memory data rate:   7008 MHz
Memory interface:   128-bit 
Memory bandwidth:   112.13 GB/s
Total available graphics memory:    12261 MB
Dedicated video memory: 4096 MB GDDR5
System video memory:    0 MB
Shared system memory:   8165 MB
Video BIOS version: 86.07.22.00.50
IRQ:            Not used
Bus:            PCI Express x8 Gen2
Device Id:      10DE 1C82 62533842
Part Number:        G210 0000

[Components]

nvui.dll        8.17.14.1694        NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdplcy.dll        8.17.14.1694        NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdbat.dll     8.17.14.1694        NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvxdapix.dll        8.17.14.1694        NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
NVCPL.DLL       8.17.14.1694        NVIDIA User Experience Driver Component
nvCplUIR.dll        8.1.940.0       NVIDIA Control Panel
nvCplUI.exe     8.1.940.0       NVIDIA Control Panel
nvWSSR.dll      25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Workstation Server
nvWSS.dll       25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Workstation Server
nvViTvSR.dll        25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Video Server
nvViTvS.dll     25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Video Server
NVSTVIEW.EXE        7.17.14.1694        NVIDIA 3D Vision Photo Viewer
NVSTTEST.EXE        7.17.14.1694        NVIDIA 3D Vision Test Application
NVSTRES.DLL     7.17.14.1694        NVIDIA 3D Vision Module
nvDispSR.dll        25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Display Server
NVMCTRAY.DLL        25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Media Center Library
nvDispS.dll     25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA Display Server
PhysX       09.11.1111      NVIDIA PhysX
NVCUDA.DLL      25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA CUDA 10.0.132 driver
nvGameSR.dll        25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA 3D Settings Server
nvGameS.dll     25.21.14.1694       NVIDIA 3D Settings Server

[Licenses]

3DTV Play
```

Plenty of RAM:

[image]

Comment: Looking at that datacenter list though, there's some on there with rather high packet loss!

Comment: @smock good point! How do i debug that? Ping seems to return perfectly 100% out of game on cmd console

Comment: I'm sure I've seen some people use pingtrace or pingplotter - but unsure if there are free versions ?? They help you identify which server along the route is the problem. Perhaps a node along the way is traffic shaping, or overloaded for bulk traffic

Comment: You know what, it may also be related to dropping larger packets. I have only tested pinging with small packets. I'll try fiddling with some large packet testing tools & report back

Comment: Ping should have an option to specify packet size. Ping -l (X)

Comment: what is your router MTU set to?

Comment: IDK, but MTU should just change throttling not actually drop packets, right? Anyway this diagnosed it https://superuser.com/a/1445371/234051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That packet loss percentage should have gave it away. It wasn't an issue with Apex Legends. When I finally saw it in another game I knew.

Pings may not show packet loss unless you send large pings! I had packet loss on my network that was invisible until I upped my ping packet size.

For windows open a command prompt and run:

`ping  -n 30 -l <largevalue> <target>`

For `largevalue` I used 40960 (40k packet)

For `target` I used the first few IP addresses from `tracert google.com`

(which was my routers & cable modem). One of the devices further down the chain had terrible packet loss (>60%) for large packets but 0% for small. I fixed it by restarting it but it could also be a cable or something internal that needs replacing.